# Textview on top of list, scrollable container

Tags: java, android

How can I make the question textview to be on top of the list, as if it was the first item of the list, letting the question stretch as down as it needs then starting the list underneath it, while both of them being scrollable by the same scroller?

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="4.34"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:padding="8dip"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. Use `ListView.addHeaderView()` instead.

Comment: will that make the question on top and the list to be scrollable by the same scroller?

Comment: yes, in this case the question will be just an additional list item and it will be scrollable as well as the other items.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need, and probably not want, a `ListView` in `ScrollBar`. The `ListView` is already scrollable. You can replace the `ScrollView` with a `RelativeView`. Then in your 'ListView` use

`android:layout_below="@+id/question_content"`

this should give you what you want. Then you shouldn't even need the `LinearLayout`